# How to filter model by its property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, model

I have a modelArr:

```
NSArray<MyModel *> *modelArr = xxx;
```

And in the `MyModel`, has property, such as `type`.

How can I filter the `modelArr` to get a new Array only have the same `type`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`NSPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate?language=objc) for that.

Compare `type` property with specific value.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = %@", searchType];
NSArray *filterArray = [modelArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

If you want to check `type` property contains specific value than

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type contains[cd] %@", searchType];
NSArray *filterArray = [modelArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSPredicate, Please use this code

```
NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[cd] %@",self.searchText.text];
self.filteredArray = [self.hotelArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
NSLog(@"HERE %@",self.filteredArray);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSArray *uniqueNames = [modelArr valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.type"];
```